# Coefficient in the polynomial power.

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

What will be equal to $p_k$ when $p_k$ is a coefficient of $x^k$ in the polynomial:

$(0.34375+0.125x+0.28125x^2+0.125x^3+0.125x^4)^n$

Comment: I wouldn't expect any simple formula for this. Do you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, why not?

Comment: Let's look at a much simpler question: what are the coefficients of $(1+2x+3x^2)^n$? These are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A084608 but no formula is given, and given the way OEIS works I take that as strong evidence that there is no simple formula.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks for the attention.